# Node JS req.body undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've looked through quite a bit of other posts and I'm very lost with this.

I can run a `console.log(req)` and get the following output

```
ServerResponse {
  ...
  req: 
   IncomingMessage {
    ...
     url: '/my-endpoint',
     method: 'POST',
     statusCode: null,
     statusMessage: null,
     ...
     body: { foo: 'bar' },
     _body: true,
     ...
     route: Route { path: '/my-endpoint', stack: [Object], methods: [Object] } },
  ...
```

Looks solid, so I would expect to do `console.log(req.body)` and get `{ foo: 'bar' }` back in the console...but nope, getting undefined

After research, I found that it may be something with my `app.js` file and specifically with a `body-parser`, however, I have all of that already

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Home Page Rendering
var index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', index);

// All other routes are kept in the `routes` module
require('./routes')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

`routes.js`

```
module.exports = function routing(app) {
  var apiClient = require('./services/apiClient');

  app.post('/get-device-info', function(err, req, res){
    console.log("/get-device-info routes");
    apiClient(req, res);
  });
};
```

`apiClient.js`

```
module.exports = function callApi(req, res){
  console.log(req);
  console.log(req.body)
};
```

`index.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here's what I've tried

`app.use(express.bodyParser());`

Ensuring that the incoming request is explicitly declaring application/json

Declaring body parser.json in other ways

Adding a config function

Comment: Which version of Express are you using? You may wish to stick to 4.x and the separate `body-parser` module, never `express.bodyParser`. Can you also include the index route function?

Comment: he does stick to separate body-parser...

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm being downvoted on this. Added more code to the OP. I am using node 7.4.0 and express 4.15.0

Comment: Please include request headers being sent to the server before the server processes them. (network tab of browser)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that Express doesn't use [error first callbacks](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) for its route handlers. The below code won't work because the `app.post` handler doesn't have the signature `(req, res) => {}`. In the below code `err` is equal to `req`, `req` is equal to `res`, and `res` is equal to `next`.

```
// routes.js
module.exports = function routing(app) {
  var apiClient = require('./services/apiClient');

  app.post('/get-device-info', function(err, req, res){
    console.log("/get-device-info routes");

    // Assuming the request is correct 
    // the value of body will be the request body  
    console.log(res.body)

    apiClient(req, res);
  });
};`
```

There are 3 different route callback signatures you can use in Express

- `(req, res) => {}` - This is the most basic and defines a route that just cares about the request and response
- `(req, res, next) => {}` - This is middleware callback signature which looks like a basic route callback but, it also assigns the `next` object which tells Express to call the next matching route.
- `(err, req, res, next) => {}` - This is the error handling route callback and you only need 1 per Express Router Middleware or Express App. It gets called if `next(err)` is called within a Route or Middleware. More specifically, if `next()` isn't called with a string or nothing it will skip all remaining Middleware and Routes and go straight to the error handler. You can read more about it in the [Express Docs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

---

You'll need to change the route definition to

```
app.post('/get-device-info', (req, res) => {
  apiClient(req, res)
})
```

Or you could even do this

```
module.exports = app => {
  let apiClient = require('./services/apiClient')

  app.post('/get-device-info', apiClient)
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something silly like this.....I didn't think the callback signature order mattered. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this, since it worked for me.

First declare `app` and then the `bodyParser`, since `bodyParser` is used within `app`:

```
const app           = express();
const bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
```

Then have these lines below:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```